# Writing a function to mimic Characters

Tags: string-manipulation, code-review, coding-style

I am working my way through Programming Paradigms via Mathematica (A First Course) and have answered the following question in lesson 25:

> Write a function of one argument "s", a String, which writes the
>   string "s" to some file and then reads the string that file back in as
>   a list of single characters.  This operation thus mimics Characters[].
>   Pay attention to the methods Mathematica has for reading in data from
>   a file.

```
In   Characters["the cow jumped over the moon"]

 Out   {t, h, e,  , c, o, w,  , j, u, m, p, e, d,  , o, v, e, r,  , t, h, e,  , m, o, o, n}
```

My function is as follows:

```
Clear[myCharacters]
myCharacters[s_String] :=
  Module[{myStream},
   myStream = OpenWrite["file2"];
   Write[myStream, s];
   Close[myStream];
   ReadList["file2", Character]
   ];
myCharacters["the cow jumped over the moon"]
```

which produces an output that includes the leading and trailing quotation marks:

```
{",t, h, e,  , c, o, w,  , j, u, m, p, e, d,  , o, v, e, r,  , t, h, e,  , m, o, o, n,"}
```

So thinking back to my previous question, where I had a couple of significant mistakes, I am wondering if there is something that I am missing or is my answer basically correct? Also I would appreciate being shown how I could improve my function even if it does give correct output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-line fix is to use [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WriteString.html) in place of [`Write`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Write.html).  This writes the literal string rather than the corresponding *Mathematica* expression, which is delimited by quotation marks.

The same thing could be accomplished by using [`BinaryWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinaryWrite.html) because as the documentation states:

> BinaryWrite[channel,"string"] writes the raw sequence of characters in a string.

To use it however you must open your stream appropriately:

```
OpenWrite["file2", BinaryFormat -> True]
```

If you are not set on using streams this can be done more simply with [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html) as unlike `Write` or [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Put.html) this function can conveniently write raw strings (again, rather than *Mathematica* String expression syntax).

```
myCharacters[s_String] := ReadList[Export["$file", s, "String"], Character]
```

Note that since `Export` returns the name of the file I used it inside `ReadList` directly.

Comment: Mr. Wizard, thank you for your help.